# Grouping in NAV 2009 RTC?

Tags: rdlc, microsoft-dynamics, navision

I am trying to print the bills which has to generate 3 copies for different purpose and this is an upgrade from 2009 classic to RTC and I am stuck at grouping part. I tried to study all the forums and links.

Can someone please help me with this.

The values to be printed are defined as the global variables, i.e the item number, description and quantity.

Can someone please help me with this as I am new to NAV.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

you can create a report with a function to print the bills, and u can call the function in the page. u can pass the global variables as parameter to the function.  So u can fetch the values over there.